# Add div element in ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some `<li>` elements, like this:

```
<ul class="some_class">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And in my css file I have:

```
.some_class > li
```

I want to change some of that `li` elements by jQuery. My idea is to have something like this:

```
<ul class="some_class">
    <div id="some_id">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </div>
    ...
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And change its by `$("#some_id").html()`. But its fails, because of css. I don't want to change css, cause its template css, and it's become very difficult to make changes in it.

Is there some other methods to perfom this?

Comment: Your idea is to change valid `html` into invalid `html`...

Comment: `UL` can have _only_ `LI` a children; and while browsers might accept you trying to insert a `DIV` in between via JS, it is not recommended, because results might not be what you expect.

Comment: I recommend adding classes to the `li` elements you wan't to change rather than wrapping them with a `div`.

Comment: div is not allowed in ul

Comment: Find a way to select the `li` elements and look into `.addClass()`.

Comment: what do you want to do with the DIV? maybe there might be a better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the two pieces of source code you provided, your problem is not the CSS per say, but the way you changed the DOM, making the CSS invalid:

**Solution 1:**

Change:

```
.some_class > li
```

To:

```
.some_class li
```

Because in your code manipulation your `<li></li>` are now direct descendants of `some_class` your CSS is broken. In CSS `>` means direct descendant.

**Solution 2:**

If you don't want to change the CSS just add a class to the `<li>` you want to change, but do not nest them inside another div.

Note: given the comments about invalid HTML: Solution 2 will not cause a problem with your HTML, and for solution one, replace `DIV` for another `UL`

Comment: But it makes the html invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to target elements, and especially with jQuery this is a breeze.

Of course you can just add a class to each of the elements you want to target, but there are lots of ways to do it without changing your markup at all.  For example, you can select using the actual index of the element within the parent using eq(); use pseudo classes like first-child, last-child; use jQuery extensions like :even or :odd; use nth-child to select repeatable patterns like every third element (nth-child:(3n+3))...